# How do i bring userelationship in this calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the number of working days between 2 date columns in a table called Incident Table and the 2 columns are called Created Date and Resolved Date. I also have a standard date table.

Right now, the relationship is one to many between date and Created date column in Incident table

First I created a column in date table that would give true or false as to whether a day was a weekday

```
Is Working Day = if('Date'[Day Name Short]="Sat",FALSE(),if('Date'[Day Name Short]="Sun",FALSE(),TRUE()))
```

Then in the incident table i used this

```
Time to Resolve (days) = COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Date', AND ( AND ( 'Date'[Date] >= 'Incidents'[Created Date], 'Date'[Date] <= Incidents[Resolved Date] ), 'Date'[Is Working Day] ) ) )
```

This formula is fine on its own but i need to connect resolved date with the date table so i can use date filter for both created and resolved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would ideally create two relationship from the Dates table with Incident table, one active and one inactive and then in the measure you would activate the inactive relationship using USERELATIONSHIP.

```
Something =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Incident[Time to Resolve (days)] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Incident[Resolved Date], Dates[Date] )
)
```